How to achieve an "are, bure, boke" look with analogue photography?
From The Photographers Gallery website,

Daido Moriyama (b. 1938, Japan), a pioneering figure in the world of
photography, has left an indelible mark with his distinctive style
often referred to in Japanese as 'are, bure, boke' - or 'grainy,
blurry, out of focus'. This approach is often associated with the
Provoke era, related to the short-lived but influential Provoke
magazine produced in late 1960s Japan.

Here are a few examples of what I'm talking about. Basically early Daido Moriyama. I think the physical flaws and uneven development of the film matters a lot so I'm reluctant to use digital tools here.
From this I would take away that you simply "underexpose", and "overdevelop", but I'm wondering if there's any more to it.





Another reference to his work here that has a video that describes his photography, but doesn't describe his processing

This is on flickr's "I Shoot Film" group with the caption "nikon f90 / prost super-ww 28;2.8 / fomapan 400 / silberra s-76 / spring 2024". I don't know enough about film to say if this helps answer the question.
